# Highest and lowest point of intercection

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

So I'm revising for my analysis exam and I'm stuck on this optimization problem.
The intersection of the plane $z+2x+y=5$ and the cylinder $$\frac{(x-1)^2}{4}+\frac{(y+1)^2}{9}=1$$ is a curve. Find its lowest and highest point.

So I built the function $\Delta(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu)= \lambda(z+2x+y-5)+\mu\left(\frac{(x-1)^2}{4}+\frac{(y+1)^2}{9}-1\right)$. Setting the partials equal to $0$ isn't getting me anywhere. Should I be treating $z$ as a function of $x,y$ in the plane?

Comment: You seemed to have introduced two Lagrange multipliers to restrict to the points on the curve; but what is the _function you are optimizing_...?

Comment: typo's intersection *  cylinder *  making a  comment about it because I have too many edits waiting

Comment: fixed them thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "lowest" and "highest" they mean with respect to the $z$-coordinate, then you can look for the extreme values of the plane, solved for $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$, where you restrict $x$ and $y$ to the points on the cylinder; that is:
$$\Delta(x,y,z,\lambda)= 5-2x-y+\lambda\left(\frac{(x-1)^2}{4}+\frac{(y+1)^2}{9}-1\right)$$
See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=optimize+(5+-+2+x+-+y)+for+(x-1)%5E2%2F4%2B(y%2B1)%5E2%2F9%3D1) to check your answer.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG $$x-1=2\cos t,y+1=3\sin t$$

$$z=5-2(1+2\cos t)+1+3\sin t=4+3\sin t-4\cos t$$

Now using [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity),  $$(3\sin t-4\cos t)^2+(3\cos t+4\sin t)^2=3^3+4^2$$

$$\implies(3\sin t-4\cos t)^2\le25\iff-5\le3\sin t-4\cos t\le5$$